# How to get the value from a Key<Entity>?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have this: `Key<Question> questionKey`. Now I'm trying to get the Question. I was looking for a method such as: `questionKey.getValue()` but there isn't one.

Is the only way using `ofy().load()`?

Comment: which value you're looking for? key id? or an entity behind this id?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov entitty

Comment: then the only way is to load it from db. key is just an identifier of an entity, a pointer to a place where it's stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load it from database. See example below.

```
Question question = ofy.load.key(questionKey).now();
```

Or you can use [Ref<T>](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify/5.1.10) instead of Key<T> that allows you to directly access the actual entity object.

```
@Entity
class Car {
    @Id Long id;
    Ref<Person> driver;    // Person is an @Entity
}

Car car = new Car();
car.driver = Ref.create(driverKey);
ofy().save().entity(car).now();

Car fetched = ofy().load().entity(car).now();
Person driver = fetched.driver.get();
```

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#relationships).